# Matching certain columns in two dataframes to get a similarity score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scoring

I have a dataframe with like one million records 'A' and a smaller dataframe with 1000 records 'B', which I want to add to dataframe 'A'.

Here's the catch: Certain records might already be in table 'A' under a slightly different name and I don't want to add duplicates. Therefore, the idea is to come up with a similarity score for the records of dataframe 'B', so that I can come up with a cutoff value, leaving me with a clean dataframe 'B' to add to dataframe 'A'.

For example: Dataframe 'A' contains one million records of a street name.

| ZIP | Street |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Flower Street 1 |
| 1234 | Rose Street 2 |
| 1234 | Dog Street 3 |
| 1234 | Cat Street 4 |
| 1234 | Mouse Street 5 |

Dataframe 'B':

| ZIP | Street |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Flowr Street 1 |
| 1234 | Unique Street 2 |
| 1234 | Dogg Ztreet 3 |
| 1234 | Unique Street 4 |
| 1234 | Mouz Str 5 |

I imagine the final table to look something like this, where I than would delete the records with a score >75% later on for example.

| ZIP | Street | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Flowr Street 1 | 90% |
| 1234 | Unique Street 2 | 5% |
| 1234 | Dogg Ztreet 3 | 78% |
| 1234 | Unique Street 4 | 1% |
| 1234 | Mouz Str 5 | 84% |

Now, before even thinking about creating a certain score I am stuck on how to pick a record just one by one of the smaller dataframe 'B' to compare it against the entire dataframe of 'A'.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Levenshtein algorithm to compare the similarity of two strings. I think that could work well for you to provide a cut off point for each record you compare.

https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/

Example code is below:-
https://github.com/iainonline/levexample.git

```
import Levenshtein as lev

a = 'compare this'
b = 'to this'

Distance = lev.distance(a.lower(), b.lower())
Ratio = lev.ratio(a.lower(), b.lower())

print('Levenshtein distance is: ', Distance)
print('Levenshtein ratio is: ', Ratio)
```

Output will be:

Levenshtein distance is:  6

Levenshtein ratio is:  0.631578947368421